# How deep does the depletion region in power diode penetrate the lightly doped n- layer under no bias?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, semiconductors

I could find references for describing the depletion layer in a power diode under **reverse bias** and the consequent classification of Non-punch through and Punch-through diodes. 
 But I couldn't find a satisfactory explanation of how the depletion layer looks like under **no bias**. **How far does the depletion layer extend into the n- layer?** My guess is that the depletion layer width is small in the heavily dopes p+ region and large in the lightly doped n- region (but less width than in reverse bias condition).

Comment: Have you read: http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/COE/elrabaa/rich%20text/coe360/Week2/Lec5%20SEP18.pdf ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for sharing the doc! I understand how it works in a regular PN junction diode, but my doubt is with the power diode with a p+ n- n+ structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to answer your question without knowing the (relative) doping levels and the width of the N region.

Usually in power diodes the n region is lightly doped and also wide to increase the reverse breakdown voltage.

At zero bias the charges in the N and P depletion regions are be the same. So if the P+ region has 2x the doping level of the N region, the P+ depletion region will be 1/2 as wide as the N depletion region.

If the N region is wide enough to contain the complete depletion region (it does not reach the N+ part) then the relative sizes of the depletion regions will match the relative doping levels.

If the N region is **not** wide enough to contain the complete depletion region so part of it is inside N+ region then things get more complex.